# Python: unpacking byte packed message

Tags: python, struct, unpack

I am trying to decode some binary messages. According to vendor document it byte pack protocol messages. The length of the byte packed part is multiple of 4 bytes. When I am trying to decode a message

```py
byte = b'\x1d7\x00\xdd \x00\x00\x00\x08I>[\x04=$50lQ\x00\x03"\x02R\t`-\xe80\x8a\x00}$\x00\n\x00\x14\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x04\x04\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x00\x00\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x00'
b'\x1d7\x00\xdd'

for i in range(0, len(byte), 4):
    
    test = byte[i:i+4]
   
    print(test)
    print(struct.unpack('>format', test)[0])
```

I am not getting any ascii like messages with any format. Just wondering if someone can help me solve this.

Comment: There is no significant amount of ASCII text in that message - `=$50lQ` is the longest single chunk, but that could just as easily be random bytes that all happened to fall within the ASCII character range.  Surely the documentation told you something more useful than just the fact that the message is a multiple of 4 bytes???

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. This is what is written in the documentation.                                                           
"The event record holds a message from one of the protocols or one of
the supported internal events. 
The event record is byte packed, which can imply additional padding bits. GZIP
then handles the record, which compresses the file before sending it.
The length of the byte packed part is always a multiple of 4 Bytes. Unused bytes
at the end are set to zero. The most significant bit (msb) appears first
in the byte field. Unused bits are always set to zero."

Comment: The part about GZIP compression is a rather important detail - you'd have to uncompress the data before any use could be made of it.  However, the sample string in the code you posted isn't valid GZIP data, so I don't know how to make any sense of it.  Is it possible that you've miscopied or truncated this data somehow?  I would expect a GZIP stream to start with `\x1F`.

Comment: This file is gzipped, I unzipped it which give the binary file that I am working on. The binary file have format instruction for other field which I could decode using unpack and instruction from the document. For example record length is defined as unsigned short and 
byte = f.read(2)
value = struct.unpack('<H', byte)[0] and it gives the byte length of 72. I was trying to decode this 72 byte, but not getting to anywhere.

Comment: @jasonharper, you are right. I understood from seeing some result of decoding that this bytes are decoded based on the vendor format for each event type. Thanks a lot for your suggestion.